# Why does this lemma hold true in this paper?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Here is [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.10313.pdf) on arXiv.

See Lemma 2：

$$ |W(s)| = \left|\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}\right| \ne 1 $$ leads to 
$$ |\zeta(s)| \ne |\zeta(1-s)|$$ when $$|W(s)| > 0$$

But how does it hold true?

Comment: It seems $|W(s)|>0$ is used only to justify the next steps.

Comment: Is the question why $\frac{|\zeta(s)|}{|\zeta(1-s)|} \ne 1$ implies $|\zeta(s)| \ne |\zeta(1-s)|$? If so, because otherwise we would have $\frac{|\zeta(s)|}{|\zeta(1-s)|} =1$.

Comment: @Pedro But we must have $$ |\zeta(1-s)| \ne 0 $$ for equation above. There seems no guarantee of this.

Comment: Isn't $W\neq 0$ a hypothesis?

Comment: Sure. I mean, when author introduced that $$W(s) = \frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}$$ there is no guarantee that $$\zeta(1-s) \ne 0$$

Comment: Why do you care about a crackpot paper?

Comment: @EricWofsey Can you help pointing out the mistakes authors have made in this paper?

Comment: If $\zeta(1-s) = 0$ then $W(s) = \frac {\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}$ is not defined..  So far as I can tell he's not saying *anything* about when $W(s)$ is undefined.

Comment: If $\zeta(1-s) = 0$ and $|W(s)| =| \frac {\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)}|=|\frac {\zeta(s)}0| > 0$.  (Gag me!)  *IF* you say that then $|\zeta(s)|\ne 0 = |\zeta(1-s)|$ because it is certainly not at all true that $\frac 00 > 0$.  But we are you worrying about instances were the function is undefined.  If you are asking why $\zeta(1-s) = 0$ is not considered ... that is a different question all together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\frac ab \ne 1$ then $a\ne b$.  You should be able to prove that.[1].

And $|\frac cd| =\frac {|c|}{|d|}$.  You should be able to prove that.  [2].

So if $|\frac ab| =\frac {|a|}{|b|} \ne 1$ then $|a| \ne |b|$.

That's all.

By the way.  If $|W(s)| = 0$ then $\left|\frac {\zeta(s)}{\zeta(1-s)} \right| = 0$ and $\zeta(s) = 0$ but $\zeta(1-x) $ can not be $0$ or that fraction would be undefined.

Comment: Thanks,  But when author introduced the definition of $W(s)$,  we can't know whether $\zeta(1-s) \ne 0$

Comment: Well, write to the author and complain.  That's a big oversight on his part.  (It really is). But for this statement that you write about I don't see there is any issue.  If $|W(s)| > 0$ then then if $\zeta(1-s) = 0$ (and if you are allowed to say $\frac k0 > 0$... which I take issue with but some do say it) then $\zeta(s) \ne 0 - \zeta(1-s)$ because you are *never* allowed to say $\frac 00 > 0$.  Ever.